# ¿Cómo actualizar un RecyclerView cuando ocurra un cambio en mi base de datos?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

Tengo el problema de que al momento de añadir un dato a la base de datos de Cloud Firestore, el recycler view no lo refleja hasta que salga de la actividad y vuelva a entrar, tengo entendido que esto es porque tengo notificar al recycler view que se añadio un dato para que refresque el adapter, SUPONGO que esto se hace con `notifyItemInserted()` pero no se como adaptarlo a mi codigo ya que me pide como parametro una position.

Esta es la activity desde donde paso los datos para agregarla a la base de datos

```
class AddIngredientesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: FirestoreViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ingredientes)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FirestoreViewModel::class.java)
        crearIngrediente()
    }

    fun crearIngrediente() {


        btn_añadir_ingrediente.setOnClickListener {
            val nombre = etxt_ingrediente_nombre.text.toString().trim()
            val precio = etxt_ingrediente_precio.text.toString().toInt()
            val cantidad = etxt_ingrediente_cantidad.text.toString().toInt()
            val unidad = etxt_ingrediente_unidad.text.toString().trim()

            viewModel.crearIngrediente(nombre, precio, cantidad, unidad)
            adapter.notifyItemInserted()


        }
    }
}
```

Y este es el adapter

```
package com.amdevops.recetas.presentation.ingredientes.recyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.amdevops.recetas.R
import com.amdevops.recetas.presentation.ingredientes.recyclerview.base.BaseViewHolder
import com.amdevops.recetas.presentation.ingredientes.recyclerview.modelo.Ingrediente
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.ingredientes_row.view.*

class RecyclerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val itemClickListener: OnIngredienteClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    interface OnIngredienteClickListener {
        fun onDeleteClick(nombre: String)
    }
    
    private var dataList = mutableListOf<Ingrediente>()

    fun setDataList(data:MutableList<Ingrediente>){
        dataList = data
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {
        return IngredientesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ingredientes_row, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is IngredientesViewHolder -> holder.bind(dataList[position], position)
            else -> IllegalArgumentException("Se olvido de pasar le ViewHolder en el bind")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (dataList.size > 0) {
            dataList.size
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    inner class IngredientesViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<Ingrediente>(itemView) {
        override fun bind(item: Ingrediente, position: Int) {
            itemView.btn_delete_ingrediente.setOnClickListener {
                itemClickListener.onDeleteClick(item.nombre)
            }
            itemView.txt_nombre_ingrediente.text = item.nombre
            itemView.txt_cantidad_ingrediente.text = item.cantidad.toString()
            itemView.txt_precio_ingrediente.text = item.precio.toString()

        }
    }

}
```

**Respondiendo a lo que preguntó Sinner of the System**

El adapter lo creo en la activitiy `IngredientesActivity` en la cual es donde se va a ver reflejado el RecyclerView con todos los ingredientes que yo vaya agregando a Cloud Firestore.

```
class IngredientesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerAdapter.OnIngredienteClickListener  {


    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerAdapter
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingredientes)
        btn_add_ingrediente.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, AddIngredientesActivity::class.java))
        }

        adapter = RecyclerAdapter(this,this)
        recyclerView_ingredientes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView_ingredientes.adapter = adapter
        observeData()

    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchIngredienteData().observe(this, {
            adapter.setDataList(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }


    override fun onDeleteClick(nombre: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "El ingrediente eliminado fue: $nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Los datos del RecyclerView los toma desde un repo que es llamado desde esta clase mediante la funcion observeData del `IngredientesActivity`

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val repo = FirebaseRepo()
    fun fetchIngredienteData():LiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>>{
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>>()
        repo.getIngredienteData().observeForever {
            mutableData.value = it
        }

        return mutableData

    }
}
```

Y a continuación esta el repo desde donde hace el set y el get de los ingredientes para poblar el RecyclerView

```
class FirebaseRepo {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid

    fun setIngredienteData(nombre:String,precio:Int,cantidad:Int,unidad:String){

        val ingredienteHashMap = hashMapOf(
            "nombre" to nombre,
            "precio" to precio,
            "cantidad" to cantidad,
            "unidad" to unidad)
        db.collection("usuarios/$uid/ingredientes")
            .add(ingredienteHashMap).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    //
                }else{
                    //
                }
            }

    }

    fun getIngredienteData():LiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>>{
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>>()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("usuarios/$uid/ingredientes").get().addOnSuccessListener {result ->
            val listData = mutableListOf<Ingrediente>()
            for(document in result){
                val nombre = document.getString("nombre")
                val precio = document.getLong("precio")?.toInt()
                val cantidad = document.getLong("cantidad")?.toInt()
                val unidad = document.getString("unidad")
                val ingrediente = Ingrediente(nombre!!,precio!!,cantidad!!,unidad!!)
                listData.add(ingrediente)
            }

            mutableData.value = listData
        }
        return mutableData

    }
}
```

"Qué hace el método viewModel.crearIngrediente?"

El metodo `viewModel.crearIngrediente` es la comunicacion entre el repo de firestore y la activity, simplemente le pasa los parametros obtenidos de la acitivty al repo

```
class FirestoreViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val repo = FirebaseRepo()

    fun crearIngrediente(nombre: String, precio: Int, cantidad: Int, unidad: String) {
        repo.setIngredienteData(nombre, precio, cantidad, unidad)

    }

}
```

"Por qué una función que no crea nada se llama crearIngrediente?"

Si te referis a la de la activity `AddIngredientesActivity`, esa funcion la hice para que el onCreate no este "sucio" por asi decir, para que se vea un poco mas limpio, la realidad no se si es una buena practica.

Comment: Fálta código. Dónde creas el adapter? Dónde llamas el método `setDataList`? Qué hace el método `viewModel.crearIngrediente`? Por qué una función que no crea nada se llama `crearIngrediente`?

Comment: Hola @SinneroftheSystem, ahi edite la pregunta respondiendo a tus preguntas, no se si faltara algo mas

Comment: Disculpa la demora, no había visto el mensaje. Sí es buena práctira separar el código en funciones pero el problema es que el nombre no describe su comportamiento. La función solamente setea un listener, no crea nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente necesitas entender que tu recyclerView no carga los elementos directamente de la base de datos sino del dataset almacenado en su adapter (en tu caso es la propiedad `dataList`). Esto significa que incluso si llamas `notifyItemInserted()` o `notifyDataSetChanged()` cada vez que agregues un objeto a la base de datos, el recyclerView no podrá mostrarlo porque ese elemento no existe en su dataset.

La solución más simple es cambiar el método de tu repositorio para que se mantenga escuchando los cambios en la base de datos y los envíe a través del liveData

```
fun getIngredienteData(): LiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Ingrediente>>()
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("usuarios/$uid/ingredientes")
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            mutableData.value = value?.toObjects(Ingrediente::class.java)
        }
    return mutableData
}
```

Para que el método `toObjects` funcione necesitas que la clase `Ingrediente` tenga un constructor que no reciba argumentos. Para eso puedes agregarle un default value a los parámetros

```
data class Ingrediente(
    val nombre: String = "",
    val precio: Int = 0,
    val cantidad: Int = 0,
    val unidad: String = ""
)
```

En tu activity `IngredientesActivity` ya tienes un observer que actualiza el dataset y notifica al adapter cada vez que el liveData cambia su valor. El problema era que el repositorio solamente leía la base de datos una vez en lugar de agregar un listener.

Esta solución funciona pero tampoco es la ideal. Lo mejor es notificar exactamente que elementos fueron modificados para reducir el trabajo del adapter y que el recyclerView pueda animar los cambios correctamente. Esto requiere mucho código extra pero afortunadamente existe la librería [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) que trae la clase  `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` con todo eso implementado. En el enlace se muestra cómo usarlo.

Comment: Es justo lo que estaba buscando!  No me habia dado cuenta de que intentaba actualizar el RecyclerView cuando en realidad tenia que buscar la forma de actualizar la dataList. Ya me ayudaste en otras preguntas y me di cuenta de que parte de la información no esta en las documentaciones oficiales de Android (O al menos eso vi, capaz no busqué bien), recomendas alguna documentación no oficial, o libro como para ampliar mi conocimiento y asi en un futuro ayudar a otras personas en este foro?

Comment: No buscaste bien, toda la información necesaria debe estar ahí. Piensa que, en algún punto, todo el contenido no oficial se originó a partir del contenido oficial, que es más que simplemente la documentación. También hay [cursos](https://developer.android.com/courses/), [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=android), un [canal de youtube](https://www.youtube.com/c/AndroidDevelopers), un [blog informativo](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/) y un [blog técnico](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers)

Comment: Pero recuerda que la habilidad de un programador no se define por su conocimiento sino por su lógica. La tecnología avanza muy rápido y lo que hayas aprendido se volverá obsoleto tarde o temprano. Hasta que alcances un nivel decente como programador, tu prioridad debería ser mejorar tu capacidad de resolver problemas antes que ampliar tu conocimiento. [Esto](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/06/kotlin-heroes-episode-7/) te puede ayudar con eso.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!